# POX (Plain-Old-Xml) service using Stream parameters

Tags: .net, xml, wcf

I want to develop a WCF service, which will receive various XMLs and save them for further processing. I can't stick to particular data type, because the incoming XMLs will be totally different. So far I've chosen the approach using Stream parameters:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IApiService
{
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "getXml",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    [OperationContract]
    Stream getXml(Stream request);
}
```

I am returning some text for response. The service will be called by external application and I want to stay away from .NET-specific issues.

Is there a better approach to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If the XML which you'll receive is always well-formed, you can use the `XElement` or `XmlElement` types as the input and return values. The former is an `IXmlSerializable` type which WCF can handle, the latter is a type treated as a special case by the WCF serializer. The advantage is that you have all the XML OM to manipulate the data, and the outgoing content-type will be set automatically for you.

If the input/output isn't necessarily well-formed XML, then your solution (with `Stream`) is the only one you can use.

Answer (score 0):

If the XML that is passed can be arbitrary, `Stream` looks a good solution. You could also use `byte[]` or even `string`.